# Identifying Europe's major road exits using QGIS

Tags: qgis, europe

Dataset from EuroGeographic and Global Roads Open Access Data Set (gROADS)  have been downloaded.

The goal is to identify the exits (geocoordinate points) of highways and primary roads (gROADS refers to them as FClass     Functional Class            1=Highway, 2=Primary).  The shape data is seen and visible with software tool QGIS, but the roads are but collections of lines.

The problem is the data set is not obvious to parse.  The EGM 2021 Dataspecification has a Data Dictionary; under the transportation section data tables a 'Feature class name' `EXITC`  with code  `AQ090` which are not found or, if present, sometimes of limited data. So for example, country code IT has no Exitc dbf file.  Yet Google and Openstreetmap have these elements.

Consulting the database files (EuroGeographic) for `ROADL` which are lines, entries have names that are repeated, thus I assume that these are segments, and thus the end-points of the segments would correspond to entry/exit points.

Yet I cannot fathom how these can be extracted from this data example.

```
OBJECTID    FCsubtype   inspireId   beginLifes  F_CODE  ICC COR EXS LLE LTN MED NAMN1   NAMN2   NAMA1   NAMA2   NLN1    NLN2    RST RSU RTE RTN RTT TEN TOL TUC SHAPE_Leng  geometry
3   1   ROADL1664975    20180614    AP030   IT  1   28  2   4   1   Autostrada dei Laghi    N_A Autostrada dei Laghi    N_A ITA N_A 1   1   E35 A9  16  1   2   7   0.00262150576963    LineString
```

How can these exits be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is not a direct answer to the question, but a path to a solution]

Openstreetmap has this data. [geofabrik.de](https://download.geofabrik.de/index-v1.json) has various regional downloads; the continental ones are rather huge, so I recommend to first examine the linked json file.

The downloaded archived have shape files, `road` being the family of interest, which then can be filtered out.  Query

```
"flcass" = 'motorway_link' OR "fclass" = 'trunk_link'
```

will generated expected data.  Note: `motorway` is the key for the actual road and line geometry, while appending `_link`  provides the nodes that access the road for these major roads.